# convert array code to arraylist C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I need to make this into an array list not an array and I do not know how to start. the program takes a file and reads the file line by line and checks the the number of times each unque character shows up.

```
       class Program
     {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Parse arguments.
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two arguments are needed.");
            return;
        }
        var inputFile = args[0];
        var outputFile = args[1];
        var asciiTable = new charfrequency[255];
        var input = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
        var output = "";

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The input file is:  <{0}>.", inputFile));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The output file is: <{0}>.", outputFile));


       // creates the asci table.
         for (var i = 0; i < asciiTable.Length; i++)
        {
            asciiTable[i] = new charfrequency();
           asciiTable[i].setCharacter((char)i);
        }

        // Parse the file line by line.
        foreach (var line in input)
        {
            foreach (var character in line)
            {
                var key = (int)character;

                if (key < 255 && key >= 0)
                {
                    asciiTable[key].increment();
                }
            }
        }

        // Write to the output string.
        foreach (var charfrequency in asciiTable)
        {
            if (charfrequency.getFrequency() > 0)
            {
                output += charfrequency.toString();
                //string.Format("{0}[{1}]: {2}{3}", charfrequency.getCharacter(),            (int)charfrequency.getCharacter(), charfrequency.getFrequency(), Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        // Write the output string to the outputFile.
        File.WriteAllText(outputFile, output);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier if you use a LINQ command. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/08/31/734383.aspx) is an article that explains how to use LINQ with a File. This isn't the complete answer, but it might move your closer to it.